# How to filter list of URLs in a jsonpath expression containing a substring in Python

Tags: python, regex, json

I've to filter the list of URLs in a jsonpath expression containing a substring in Python, I've tried the following but not able to get the desired results.

I referred to http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/ and http://mikelev.in/2012/08/implementing-jsonpath-in-python-with-examples/

Here are the details of all what I have tried:

My json response:

```
{
  "127.0.0.1": {
    "URLs": [
      "http://www.test.ca/", 
      "http://b.scorecardresearch.com/p?ns__t=1387392184071&ns__c=ISO-8859-1&c1=3&c3=_es_7948950&c4=56568219&c5=105139691&c6=&c10=1&c11=1016510&c13=728x90&c16=dfa&c2=14397547&ax_iframe=2&ns_ce_mod=vce_st&ns__p=1387391507295&ax_cid=14397547&ax_bl=0&ax_blt=1228&ns_ad_event=show&ns_ad_id=DCF277937840&ns_ad_sz=728x90", 
      "http://cdn.media.ca/a/mediative/sites/test_en.js", 
      "http://pt200233.unica.com/ntpage.gif?js=1&ts=1387392184554.791&lc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.ca%2F%3Fni_title%3D%2Fhome%2Fhomepage&rf=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.ca%2F&rs=1680x1050&cd=32&ln=en&tz=GMT%20-05%3A00&jv=1&ck=UnicaID%3DwQVZatfvXZ5-YZ0yaPj&m.pn=homepage&m.mlc=%2Fhome&m.cv_c13=ctest-new&m.cv_c14=en&m.utv=ut.ctest.2.2.131022.74&m.host=www.test.ca&m.page=%2Fhome%2Fhomepage&m.mlc0=home&ets=1387392184559.194&site=test", 
    ]
  }
}
```

Above Json response is parsed as:

```
parsed_input = json.loads(urllib.urlopen('<URL for the above JSON response>').read())
```

To get the list of all URLs from the JSON response, I tried the following, which works great:

`'\n'.join(jsonpath.jsonpath(parsed_input, '$..URLs[*]')`)

Output:

```
http://www.test.ca/
http://b.scorecardresearch.com/p?ns__t=1387392184071&ns__c=ISO-8859-1&c1=3&c3=_es_7948950&c4=56568219&c5=105139691&c6=&c10=1&c11=1016510&c13=728x90&c16=dfa&c2=14397547&ax_iframe=2&ns_ce_mod=vce_st&ns__p=1387391507295&ax_cid=14397547&ax_bl=0&ax_blt=1228&ns_ad_event=show&ns_ad_id=DCF277937840&ns_ad_sz=728x90"    
http://cdn.media.ca/a/mediative/sites/test_en.js"    
http://pt200233.unica.com/ntpage.gif?js=1&ts=1387392184554.791&lc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.ca%2F%3Fni_title%3D%2Fhome%2Fhomepage&rf=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.ca%2F&rs=1680x1050&cd=32&ln=en&tz=GMT%20-05%3A00&jv=1&ck=UnicaID%3DwQVZatfvXZ5-YZ0yaPj&m.pn=homepage&m.mlc=%2Fhome&m.cv_c13=ctest-new&m.cv_c14=en&m.host=www.test.ca&m.page=%2Fhome%2Fhomepage&m.mlc0=home&ets=1387392184559.194&site=test
```

Next I've to retrieve only those URLs that contain the word "unica".
I've tried everything below, but receive the TypeError,
what am I missing?:

```
'\n'.join(jsonpath.jsonpath(parsed_input, '$..URLs[?(/unica/)]'))
'\n'.join(jsonpath.jsonpath(parsed_input, '$..URLs[?(@(unica))]'))
'\n'.join(jsonpath.jsonpath(parsed_input, '$..URLs[?(@.(*.unica.*))]'))
'\n'.join(jsonpath.jsonpath(parsed_input, '$.*.URLs[?(unica)]'))
'\n'.join(jsonpath.jsonpath(parsed_input, '$.*.URLs[?:unica]'))
```

thanks,
Sam

Comment: `[x for x in '\n'.join(jsonpath.jsonpath(parsed_input, '$..URLs[*]')) if 'unica' in x]`

Comment: hey Nehal, it prints [], anything missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ? operator introduces a script element which runs in Python so needs to use Python syntax.

In this case you could use:

```
print '\n'.join(jsonpath.jsonpath(parsed_input, "$..URLs[?('unica' in @)]"))
```

A useful option for these cases is to use the debug option via:

```
jsonpath.jsonpath(parsed_input, '$..URLs[?(/unica/)]',debug=True)
```

This prints out various output including:

```
evalx /unica/
eval /unica/
invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)
```

The line "eval /unica/" shows you what is being run in Python so you can see what is failing.

Comment: Thanks Peter for your sharing the solution & the suggestion to use debug option! It works!!

Comment: Here for JavaScript: `jsonPath(parsed_input, "$..URLs[?( /unica/.test(@) )]")`

Answer (score 0):

Following Peter's explanation, you can actually use a regular expression in [jsonpath](https://pypi.org/project/jsonpath/) filter expression if need be, using the [dunder import](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__) built-in.

```
jsonpath.jsonpath(parsed_input, "$..URLs[?(__import__('re').match('.*unic', @))]")
```

Upon further look, `jsonpath` is a collection of hacks, specifically there's this line:

```
# Get caller globals so eval can pick up user functions!!!
caller_globals = sys._getframe(1).f_globals
```

Hence, if `re` is imported in the module from where you call `jsonpath.jsonpath` this would as well:

```
jsonpath.jsonpath(parsed_input, "$..URLs[?(re.match('.*unic', @))]")
```